# TFE_Py_RecordGradient error using Keras with Tensorflow back end

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network using Keras and Tensorflow on a Nvidia GPU.  I have tried using code and data that implement very simple models models with no lock. Every network I try to define gives me the same error:

> File "", line 2, in 
>       model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))>
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/models.py", line 463, in add
>       name=layer.name + '_input')
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1457, in Input
>       input_tensor=tensor)
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1366, in **init**
>       name=self.name)
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 507, in placeholder
>       x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
>
> File "/home/smalldave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1734, in placeholder
>       return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
>
> File "/home/smalldave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4929, in placeholder
>       "Placeholder", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result, name)
>
> File "/home/smalldave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 162, in _record_gradient
>       return pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_RecordGradient(op_name, inputs, attrs,
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TFE_Py_RecordGradient'

Does anyone know the source of this error?

Here is an example of a network I tried to define:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.summary()
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, I gather you're using [`keras`](https://keras.io/#installation) and not [`tf.keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras), which is packaged with the TensorFlow installation.

`tf.keras` implements the API spec defined in keras.io but adds additional TensorFlow-specific functionality, such as support for eager execution.

So, I suspect all you need to do is change from something like:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Hope that helps.